# Working out a cost on a table of ranges

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

I have two tables similar to the one below:

```
ItemTable
-----------------------------
ItemId | NumberPurchased
1      | 10
2      | 90
```

I need to figure out the total cost of an order based on the table below that holds a sliding scale of price per item depending on number ordered:

```
PriceBands
-----------------------------
ScaleId | LowerLimit | UpperLimit | CostPerItem
1       | 1          | 5          | 10
2       | 6          | 10         | 9
3       | 11         | 20         | 8
...
```

I need to somehow work out the total cost and join that on the first table (the items).

Can anyone help please?

Just to be clear for ItemId 1 the calculation would be as follows:

```
NumberPurchased = 10
(5 * 10) + (5 * 9)  = 95
```

The banding banding comes into affect only on items over the upper limit.

Comment: If you want to join any two tables you must have key to join on. In you example I don't see such key. Probably you forgot to add `PriceBands.ItemId` foreign key.

Comment: The first two tables have an order `ID`entifier column ?

Comment: @Burt: What happens if `NumberPurchased` is between `1` and `5` (first range) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the same price for every item, something like this might do the trick:

```
SELECT i.itemID, i.NumberPurchased, i.NumberPurchased * p.costPerItem as "Cost"
FROM itemTable i, PriceBands p
WHERE i.NumberPurchased >= p.LowerLimit 
      AND i.NumberPurchased <= p.UpperLimit;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/270e71/1)</kbd>

If you want different prices for the items you must put an itemId inside priceBands AND JOIN the two tables on that itemId.

---

To handle incremenental costs for each tier of number purchased, you can do:

```
SELECT i.itemID, i.NumberPurchased, SUM((
      CASE 
        WHEN i.NumberPurchased > p.upperLimit
          THEN p.upperLimit
        ELSE i.NumberPurchased - p.LowerLimit + 1
        END
      ) * p.costPerItem) AS "Cost"
FROM itemTable i, PriceBands p
WHERE i.NumberPurchased > p.LowerLimit
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

This will go through every line in the PriceBands table while `i.NumberPurchased > p.LowerLimit`, SUM'ing while doing :

- multiply `p.costPerItem` with `p.upperLimit` while `i.NumberPurchased > p.upperLimit`. (5 * 10);
- multiply `p.costPerItem` with i.NumberPurchased - p.lowerLimit`+ 1. (9 * 10-6 + 1 . This`+ 1`is to include the`lowerLimit` number also).

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/270e71/13)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks Filipe that is exactly what I need, really appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

If there were a foreign key in PriceBands table the query would return that you asked:

```
select it.itemId, pb.costPerItem
from ItemTable it, 
     PriceBands pb
where it.itemId = pb.itemId
and it.numberPurchased >= pb.LowerLimit
and it.numberPurchased <= pb.upperLimit;
```